# Load multiple fragment and adding it to backstack in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment-backstack

I have 1 `Activity` and 3 `fragments` they're `FirstFragment`, `SecondFragment` & `ThirdFragment` respectively.

`FirstFragment` loads automatically when `MainActivity` is open.
`SecondFragment` loads by Button click of `FirstFragment` with `addToBackStack` flag. same thing goes with `ThirdFragment`.

Now, suppose user closes the app when `SecondFragment` is displaying on its screen, than when user opens the app again, he should directly switch to `SecondFragment` (internally `FirstFragment` loads than `SecondFragment` loads with `addToBacStack` flag).

How to achieve this?

Here's some code. currently, I'm unable to load multiple fragment.

`SharePreferences` for current displaying `fragment`.

```
public class PrefsMain {

    public static final String TAG = Prefs.class.getSimpleName();

    // Strings contains Fragment names BEGIN
    public static final String CurrentFragment_RoleSelectionFragment =
            RoleSelectionFragment.TAG;
    public static final String CurrentFragment_CheckInOutFragment =
            CheckInOutFragment.TAG;
    public static final String CurrentFragment_TeacherRegFragment =
            TeacherRegFragment.TAG;
    public static final String CurrentFragment_StudentSelectionFragment =
            StudentSelectionFragment.TAG;
    public static final String CurrentFragment_StudentFragment =
            StudentFragment.TAG;
    public static final String CurrentFragment_StudentRegistrationFragment =
            StudentRegistrationFragment.TAG;
    public static final String CurrentFragment_DiagnoseFragment =
            DiagnoseFragment.TAG;
    // Strings contains Fragment names END

    // SharedPreferences KEY
    private static final String CurrentFragment = "Fragment";

    private SharedPreferences mPrefs;

    public PrefsMain(Context context) {
        mPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(TAG, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    // Getter - Setter
    public String getCurrentFragment() {
        return mPrefs.getString(CurrentFragment, CurrentFragment_RoleSelectionFragment);
    }

    public void setCurrentFragment(String currentFragment) {
        mPrefs.edit().putString(CurrentFragment, currentFragment).apply();
    }
}
```

`MainAvtivity.java`

```
import static com.odoo.addons.employees.utils.PrefsMain.CurrentFragment_CheckInOutFragment;
import static com.odoo.addons.employees.utils.PrefsMain.CurrentFragment_DiagnoseFragment;
import static com.odoo.addons.employees.utils.PrefsMain.CurrentFragment_RoleSelectionFragment;
import static com.odoo.addons.employees.utils.PrefsMain.CurrentFragment_StudentFragment;
import static com.odoo.addons.employees.utils.PrefsMain.CurrentFragment_StudentRegistrationFragment;
import static com.odoo.addons.employees.utils.PrefsMain.CurrentFragment_StudentSelectionFragment;
import static com.odoo.addons.employees.utils.PrefsMain.CurrentFragment_TeacherRegFragment;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private PrefsMain mPrefsMain;
    private AppCompatActivity mActivity;

    private RoleSelectionFragment mRoleSelectionFragment;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mActivity = this;
        mPrefsMain = new PrefsMain(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // simply get the fragment name from `SharedPreferences`.
        // and loads it 
        final String currentFragment = mPrefsMain.getCurrentFragment();
        if (currentFragment.equals(CurrentFragment_RoleSelectionFragment)) {
            loadFragment(RoleSelectionFragment.newInstance(), 
                            RoleSelectionFragment.TAG);
        } else if (currentFragment.equals(CurrentFragment_CheckInOutFragment)) {
            loadFragment(CheckInOutFragment.newInstance(), 
                            CheckInOutFragment.TAG);
        } else if (currentFragment.equals(CurrentFragment_TeacherRegFragment)) {
            loadFragment(TeacherRegFragment.newInstance(), 
                            TeacherRegFragment.TAG);
        } else if (currentFragment.equals(CurrentFragment_StudentSelectionFragment)) {
            loadFragment(StudentSelectionFragment.newInstance(), 
                            StudentSelectionFragment.TAG);
        } else if (currentFragment.equals(CurrentFragment_StudentFragment)) {
            loadFragment(StudentFragment.newInstance(), 
                            StudentFragment.TAG);
        } else if (currentFragment.equals(CurrentFragment_StudentRegistrationFragment)) {
            loadFragment(StudentRegistrationFragment.newInstance(), 
                            StudentRegistrationFragment.TAG);
        } else if (currentFragment.equals(CurrentFragment_DiagnoseFragment)) {
            loadFragment(DiagnoseFragment.newInstance(), 
                            DiagnoseFragment.TAG);
        }
    }

    public void loadFragment(Fragment fragment, String TAG) {
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.flMain, fragment, TAG)
                .commit();
    }
}
```

<br/ ><br/ >
Above implementation just loads the last known `fragment` but, it doesn't perform `addToBackStack` for its parent `fragments`.

Comment: try adding    android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true" to the activity tag of MainActivity in your Manifest

Comment: What to do you mean by close the app... Kill it and come back again ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not adding the transaction to backstack. Add your transaction to backstack.

```
public void loadFragment(Fragment fragment, String TAG) {
    getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.flMain, fragment, TAG)
            .addToBackStack(TAG)
            .commit();
}
```